# What is the original form of _api/web/lists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I'm working with REST in SharePoint 2010.
What is the original form of [http://server/site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(‘Title’)](/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(%E2%80%98Title%E2%80%99)) in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following REST endpoints could be used to request List resource:

- SharePoint 2013: `http://<site url>/web/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle(<ListTitle>)`
- SharePoint 2010: `http://<site url>/web/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ListTitle`